# What is the best way to use functions of Controller and Conn in Plug Module?

Tags: phoenix-framework, plug

I want to write my own plug in my phoenix app. The plug is to check the cookies and render the error page if cookies don't exist. Similar to the 404 error. Based on the logic, those functions below may be called:

- `put_status`: set the status code of response, I set to 422.
- `put_view`: My error page is located in `templates/error/422.html.eex`, so the `ErrorView` should be included.
- `render`: Render the html page.
- `halt`: halt the connection.

```
conn
|> put_status(422)
|> put_view(ErrorView)
|> render("422.html")
|> halt()
```

`put_status` and `halt` are in `Plug.Conn`. `put_view` and `render` are in `Phoenix.Controller`. I know that I can use the full namespace to call those functions, but it looks redundant. So I am considering `import/use/alias` functions as well.

For `Plug.Conn`, the Programming Phoenix 1.4 Book uses `import​ Plug.Conn`, some official plug uses `alias Plug.Conn`.

For `Phoenix.Controller`, I haven't found any example, but `import` could work. Is it not recommended to use Controller functions in Plug?

I am considering both the code simplify, readability and performance. Does anyone know what's the best practice for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can import `Phoenix.Controller` and `Plug.conn` in your plug and import that plug into the controller.

```
defmodule DubberConnectWeb.CheckCookie do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Phoenix.Controller

  def check_cookie(conn, _opts) do
    if <check cookie existence condition..> do
     conn
     |> put_status(422)
     |> put_view(DubberConnectWeb.ErrorView)
     |> render("422.html")
     |> halt()
    else
     conn
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you will just do

```
import DubberConnectWeb.CheckCookie
plug(:check_cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the alias/import, neither of them causes a performance loss.

In the `import` doc, it says:

> We use import whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules without using the fully-qualified name.

And alias does it too, with the namespace included.

Therefore, both `alias Plug.Conn` and `import Plug.Conn` are good to use in the plug module.